# What causes the rim of the droplet to stop moving in the Marangoni effect?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, evaporation

This is specifically concerning a set-up where a droplet containing a mixture of water and alcohol is deposited on the surface of vegetable oil in a petri dish. I want to know what causes the inner droplet to spread out to its maximum and then recede, as well as the alcohol concentration at the rim of the droplet at its ,maximum. How does this have to do with the spreading parameter? the inner droplet refers to the dark droplet in the centre from which droplets are emerging from.

[image]

Comment: Did you seen this paper https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.074504 ?

Comment: yeap ive read that paper, while they said that spreading only occurred for an alcohol concentration above the critical alcohol concentration, wast explicitly stated that it was that concentration at the edge of the droplet, so i just wanted to check if I was correct. Thanks